# How to catch elements from a m*n matrix by an n array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For example, I have A matrix and an array B:

```
A = [1 2 3 4
     4 5 6 7
     7 8 9 10];

B = [2 1 3 2]
```

`B` represents a list of indices of `A`, which means I want to get the result like this:

```
[4 2 9 7]
```

(the 2nd element of [1 4 7] is 4; the 1st element of [2 5 8] is 2...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sub2ind` to get this. We use `B` as the row indices and `1:size(A,2)` as the column indices. `sub2ind` then converts these to linear indices which we can use to index into `A`.

```
C = A(sub2ind(size(A), B, 1:size(A, 2)));
```

You could also compute the linear indices directly without using `sub2ind` for a performance improvement.

```
C = A(((1:size(A, 2)) - 1) * size(A, 1) + B)
```